# How can i add a new tab in the admin panel of Opencart and get it working?

Tags: web, opencart, admin, forum

Hello stackoverflowers ,
I have added a new tab "DELIVERYBOY" inside partner account .I have created a form inside the tab . But how to get it working . To store data inside the admin . Take a look at the image below .

[Please see this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yovOq.jpg)

Comment: do you want "DELIVERYBOY"s info to be saved when the user press the "save"  button up there?

Comment: Yes Abdo Adel . You are right ..  I want the data to be saved when when " save " button is pressed .

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure , but maybe you mean " To store the data inside the admin" **IS** " To store the data inside the database ".

To save to database

1. Make sure you already have buttons and action in your form. (view)
2. Load language, get language button & action for button (controller).

   `$this->data['action'] = $this->url->link('data1/data2/validation', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'], 'SSL');`

It's mean  in admin/controller/data1/data2.php/(function)validation.

2. Load model, save any data to variable then save it back to the array for easy storage, then passing array to model for executed.

Hope it's helping.